# How do I access user configuration inside a dag file for airflow?

Tags: airflow, databricks

I want to pass the configuration which will be submitted through web ui to DatabricksSubmitRunOperator's notebook_task parameter.

I know how to do this in python operator but not in databrick operator.

Comment: what kind of configuration ? `notebook_taks` just a Python dictionary that you can form as you want

Comment: Yes it is a python dictionary. When we run a dag there are 2 options - run with configuration and run without configuration. So I want to access the configuration passed at this time.